# SQL Server Mirroring - endpoint permissions - why grant connect to SQL service account?

Tags: sql-server

SQL 2008 R2
Implementing database mirroring.
Mirroring endopoints created on both partner servers (principal and mirror) and on the witness.

Was planning to GRANT CONNECT permissions on the mirroring endpoints to the domain account under which the database servers (partners and witness) are running.

Question: Why do we need to create a database server login for this domain account on each database server? The domain account should already have full priviliges on the database servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement to create a login for the peer and grant connect permission is required only if such a permission is necessary. If the peers (and witness) run under a service account that already has the required privileges, then the grant is not technically required.

However I would recommend that, whatever you do, do it **consistently**. If all your DBM deployments always create a login for the peer(s) and grant connect permission on the DBM endpoint, then do it everywhere, *even if not required*. If you decide that the explicit logic/connect permission is not necessary, be consistent and don't add this login anywhere.